# View function is not called from urls.patterns

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

My view's function are not called by urls.py patterns. I can only call them explicitly.

Basic Layout is

```
--project
----persons
----project
```

`project/urls.py` is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include, patterns
from .views import page   #irrelevant
# from persons import views as person_views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w./-]+)/$', page, name='page'), #irrelevant
    url(r'^$', page, name='homepage'),                #irrelevant
    url(r'^persons/', include('persons.urls', namespace='persons')),  # WORKS
#   url(r'^persons/$', person_views.persons, name='persons'),   #wont work
#   url(r'^persons/add/$', person_views.add_person, name='add_person'),  #wont work
)
```

Everything is ok until this point, since persons.urls is included successfully... But inside:

`persons/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
#from persons.views import index_persons, add_person
from persons import views

#views.index_persons('GET / HTTP/1.0')  # >>> WORKS - function called <<< !!!

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'.', views.index_persons, name='index_persons'), # DOES NOT WORK
    url(r'^add/', views.add_person, name='add_person'),   # DOES NOT WORK
)
```

I have also tried other regex like:

```
    url(r'*', views.index_persons, name='index_persons'), # DOES NOT WORK
    url(r'^$', views.index_persons, name='index_persons'), # DOES NOT WORK
```

no luck...

My `persons/views.py` file contains:

```
def index_persons(request):
    print 'WHY???'

def add_person(request):
    print 'WHY???'
```

'WHY???' is normally printed in the console (stdout - since I execute from manage.py runserver), when the **index_persons function is called explicitly** from persons/urls.py

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `project/urls.py`, move the `page` url pattern below the other ones. Otherwise, a request to `/persons/` will be matched by the `page` url pattern first.

```
url(r'^$', page, name='homepage'),
url(r'^persons/', include('persons.urls', namespace='persons')),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w./-]+)/$', page, name='page'),
```

Inside `persons/urls.py`, you should have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index_persons, name='index_persons'),
    url(r'^add/$', views.add_person, name='add_person'),
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alasdair. To be precise I had to put the `r'^persons/` rule below both the other statements.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I got the order wrong when I copy-pasted before, I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your url rule should be

```
url(r'^/?$, views.index_persons, name='index_persons'),
```

**NOTE 1**: Don't forget to restart the server.

**NOTE 2**: `namespace='persons'` is equal to not set `namespace`, because your `url` is `persons/` is the same.

Comment: That second note is not true, Django doesn't take the namespace from the url pattern. If you don't set it, the urls are not namespaced.

Comment: @knbk I mean, is the same because your url pattern and namespace will be the same.

Comment: Ok, maybe I just misunderstood. If you mean that the matching path will be the same regardless of namespace, you're right. Not (explicitly) setting the namespace or setting it to `'persons'` makes a huge difference when reversing urls, though.